# Given an existing key how to get the next or previous key in an ordered typescript string enum?

Tags: typescript, enums

Having a key `STEPS.GENDER` and the the following string enum

```
export enum STEPS {
  NAME = "name",
  GENDER = "gender",
  BIRTHDAY = "birthday",
  SUCCESS = "success"
}
```

How can I dynamically get the next or previous key in enum, In this case `STEPS.BIRTHDAY` and `STEPS.NAME`?

PS: Or in general any other key in relation to the key at hand where I can define the relation. If no existing key found `undefined` can be returned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increment an Enum in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719812/how-to-increment-an-enum-in-typescript)

Comment: @depperm not a duplicate of the question you linked - here we have string enum, not numeric enum

Comment: I tend to stay away from `enum` if I need any more functionality; you can mostly get the same functionality yourself with an `enum`-like object... something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/kNrg5m).  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64558250/generic-function-to-merge-multiple-typescript-enums) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56992173/typescript-extending-enum) for places where my answer is "build your own `enum`-like object".  If you want I can write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look how string enum is transpiled to JS:

```
var STEPS;
(function (STEPS) {
    STEPS["NAME"] = "name";
    STEPS["GENDER"] = "gender";
    STEPS["BIRTHDAY"] = "birthday";
    STEPS["SUCCESS"] = "success";
})(STEPS || (STEPS = {}));
```

Knowing that:

```
 enum STEPS {
  NAME = "name",
  GENDER = "gender",
  BIRTHDAY = "birthday",
  SUCCESS = "success"
}

const vals = Object.values(STEPS);

const indexOfSearchedItem = vals.indexOf(STEPS.GENDER);
const next: STEPS = vals[indexOfSearchedItem + 1]
console.log(next);
```

Comment: Is `enum` ordering emitted to JS guaranteed to be the same as the ordering in the TS?  Is the ordering of `Object.values()` guaranteed to be the same as insertion order in the target runtime environment?  Those are both probably true, but I'd feel antsy relying on it.

Comment: @jcalz Good points. I took first one for granted, and was under impression that the latter is true for ES6+: See [[OwnPropertyKeys]] (Used by Object.values) https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys
(1) increasing numeric keys (eg, 0, 1, 2), followed by
(2) non-numeric keys in insertion order, followed by
(3) symbols in insertion order.

Comment: Yes, and most people probably use ES2015+ environments... for anyone out there trying to support ES5  or ES3  I guess they are used to caveats anyway.

Comment: hey @Lesiak could you also give a way for non-string enums? There is an outdated answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719812/how-to-increment-an-enum-in-typescript but modern Typescript doesn't like it